# Python SDK 2.0 list_org_sheets method

Tags: python, smartsheet-api

The **list_org_sheets** method appears in both the *Users* and Sheets classes.
Is the version in Users merely an oversight or is it related to the

```
GET /users/sheets
```

direct API call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both entry points are identical and map to the underlying `GET /users/sheets` API call.

Comment: OK, then it is only the examples that are wrong in the SDK. They both use smartsheet.Sheets.list_org_sheets()  - wouldn't 1 coded method and the other using it be better than two methods with the same name that could potentially do different things if someone forgets to update both?